# Error in .subset(x, j) : invalid subscript type 'list'

Tags: r, bioinformatics, bioconductor

So I'm pretty new to R, so if someone could help me out that would be great.

I'm using a program called NOISeq, which is an R based piece of software which detects differential gene expression between a number of factors. I've read in a table to a data frame which looks like this:

```
            X10G48 X35Y87 X36W26 X23Y79 X2B84 X12Y30 X10B70 X10G87 X36W62
XLOC_000001     33     34     39     74    43     43     34     28     42
XLOC_000002     17     42     44     67    38     58     41     29     25
XLOC_000003      0      0      0      0     0      0      6      0      0
XLOC_000004      0      0      0      2     0      0     10      0      0
XLOC_000005     44     57     37     71    45     47     49     53     36
XLOC_000006     43     46     42     71    53     53     49     48     18
            X23Y70 X2UNA X12Y47 X10R99
XLOC_000001     82    38     28     23
XLOC_000002     58    53     28     27
XLOC_000003      0     0      0     12
XLOC_000004      0     0      4      2
XLOC_000005     47    67     48     39
XLOC_000006     53    61     37     26
```

The table is sorted by two factors, such that `10G48, 35Y87, 36W26, 23Y79, 2B84, 12Y30, 10B70` are all condition `1`, and `10G87, 36W62, 23Y70, 2UNA, 12Y47, 10R99` are all condition `2`.

I've used the code:

```
library(NOISeq)
setwd("/home/user/edgeR")
data.frame <- read.table("nalphavbeta.txt", header=TRUE, sep='\t', row.names=1)
myfactors=data.frame(c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2))
sam<-readData(data=data.frame, factors=myfactors)
myRPKM = rpkm(assayData(sam)$exprs, k = 0, lc = 1)
head(myRPKM[, 1:4])
mynoiseqbio = noiseqbio(sam, k=0.5, norm="rpkm", factor=NULL, lc = 1, r = 20, adj = 1.5, plot = FALSE, a0per = 0.9, random.seed = 12345, filter = 2)
```

But it returns the error

```
Error in .subset(x, j) : invalid subscript type 'list'
```

I have a feeling it's to do with the factors argument, but I'm not sure exactly what. Any help would be much appreciated - thanks!

Comment: Which line causes the error? The last one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved

I just needed to change the line

```
myfactors=data.frame(c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2))
```

to

```
myfactors=data.frame(caste= c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2))
```

i.e. give the factor a name, then add the factor level into the function

```
mynoiseqbio = noiseqbio(sam, k=0.5, norm="rpkm", factor=caste, lc = 1, r = 20, adj = 1.5, plot = FALSE, a0per = 0.9, random.seed = 12345, filter = 2)
```